# Customer value resolver with automapper global but only for a specific map?

Tags: automapper

For each member of a specific type in a Mapping, i want to use my specific custom value resolver.

The way I'm doing it now is defining this custom value resolver for each and every member that needs it. This is the current code:

I only want to specify this one, for a specific map, but for all my googling and searching I couldn't find a solution to this. Any ideas? Note: It's not global for all Mappings, only for a specific Mapping !

Here's the current code:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<csp_CheckSLAForPeriodByHour_Result, CheckSlaItem>()
    // make doubles into 0 instead of null
    .ForMember(p => p.Avg_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.avg_ms))
    .ForMember(p => p.Mdn_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.mdn_ms))
    .ForMember(p => p.Sla_i_wefu, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.sla_i_wefu))
    .ForMember(p => p.Sla_iw_efu, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.sla_iw_efu))
    .ForMember(p => p.Std_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.std_ms))
    // make ints into 0 instead of null
    .ForMember(p => p.Min_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IntValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.min_ms))
    .ForMember(p => p.Max_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IntValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.max_ms))
    ;
```

I would like something simple as:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<csp_CheckSLAForPeriodByHour_Result, CheckSlaItem>()
.ForAllMembers().OfType(double?).ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>()
```

Would be grateful for any solution to this!

Brgds Rickard Robin

Comment: Are you not able to make the destination property types `double` (instead of `double?`). If you do that, the destination properties will be initialized to `0D` and you won't have to worry about automapper.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution, but even so - in this case for this certain map i'd like this to happen anyway. I can imagine multiple scenarios where one desire similar functionality. That is using a resolver on all members for a certain type on only a specific map.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this?  I'm fighting the same mess right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answers is - you cannot do this! You have to write the above code for each and every property.

My solution was to remove AutoMapper and never touch it again. It isn't worth the hassle and too difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a way which might not have been the case 2 years ago.
So you can replace this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<csp_CheckSLAForPeriodByHour_Result, CheckSlaItem>()
    // make doubles into 0 instead of null
    .ForMember(p => p.Avg_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.avg_ms))
    .ForMember(p => p.Mdn_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.mdn_ms))
    .ForMember(p => p.Sla_i_wefu, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.sla_i_wefu))
    .ForMember(p => p.Sla_iw_efu, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.sla_iw_efu))
    .ForMember(p => p.Std_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.std_ms))
    // make ints into 0 instead of null
    .ForMember(p => p.Min_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IntValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.min_ms))
    .ForMember(p => p.Max_ms, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IntValueOrZeroResolver>().FromMember(p => p.max_ms))
    ;
```

With this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<csp_CheckSLAForPeriodByHour_Result, CheckSlaItem>()
    // make doubles into 0 instead of null
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DoubleValueOrZeroResolver>());
```

All the member of `csp_CheckSLAForPeriodByHour_Result` will be converted using the `DoubleValueOrZeroResolver` convertor when mapped to `CheckSlaItem`.